# JPA select query on ManyToMany

Tags: sql, database, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

Can anybody help me with SELECT query on this ManyToMany connection? I want to select enrolled users specified by id of user in my EJB class.

Course entity snippet

```
        Public class Course implements Serializable {
    ...
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

            @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name="course_user", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
        private List<User> enrolledStudents;
    ...
```

User Entity snippet

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="enrolledStudents")
    private List<Course> enrolledCourses;
...
```

For example this is my another select query in EJB, but it is not on ManyToMany. I want something similar, but can not figure out how..

```
 public List<Course> findOwndedCourses(long id) {
    TypedQuery<Course> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Course c WHERE c.owner.id = :ownerId", Course.class);
    query.setParameter("ownerId", id);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Thank you for help guys!!

Comment: What do you mean by "select enrolled users specified by id of user"? Do you want to select users for a given Course id?

Comment: Hi David.. I am speaking about this

/**
     * Find courses, where is user with id (userId) enrolled.
     * param userId, id of user.
     * return list of users enrolled courses.
     */
    List<Course> findEnrolledCourses(long userId);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should do it:

```
select c FROM Course c JOIN c.enrolledStudents u WHERE u.id = :userId
```

or this one may be simpler (the join is implicit):

```
FROM Course c WHERE c.enrolledStudents.id = :userId
```